# get_or_create for two related models and formsets

Tags: django, forms, get, inline

I have two models related by a ForeignKey and inline formsets:

```
class Balanta(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering=['data']
        verbose_name_plural="Balante"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.data)

class Conturi(models.Model):
    cont=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cont_debit=models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
    cont_credit=models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
    balanta = models.ForeignKey(Balanta)

    class Meta:
        #oredering=['cont']
        verbose_name_plural="Conturi"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.cont)
```

I have formsets based on the two models. After i submit the form, if the "Balanta part of the form" exists, the form shouldn't do anything an dif it doesn't exists it should save it in the database (I managed to do this).

Now what i want to do on the "Conturi part of the form" is to see if the cont is on the database, the form should update it with the value in the input box and if it is not in the db, the form should create it and the corresponding cont_debit or cont_credit. The current state gives me: get_or_create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list.

I think is something bigger then mt simple/newbie way to solve the problem.

Here is the view:

****LAST UPDATE****

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from sitfin.models import Balanta, Conturi
from sitfin.forms import BalantaForm , ConturiForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

def balanta_introducere(request):
    balanta=Balanta()
    ConturiInlineFormSet=inlineformset_factory(Balanta, Conturi, extra=3)
    if  request.method=='POST':
        balanta_form=BalantaForm(request.POST, instance=balanta)
        if balanta_form.is_valid():
            balanta, created=Balanta.objects.get_or_create(**balanta_form.cleaned_data)
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/sitfin/balantaok')
        formset=ConturiInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=balanta)
        if formset.is_valid():
            #formset.save()
            for form in formset:
                data={
                        'cont':form.cleaned_data.get('cont'),
                        'cont_debit':form.cleaned_data.get('cont_debit'),
                        'cont_credit':form.cleaned_data.get('cont_credit'),
                        'balanta':form.cleaned_data.get('balanta'),
                }
                try:
                    c=Conturi()#.objects.get(cont=data['cont'])
                except Conturi.DoesNotExist:
                    cont_complete,created=Conturi.objects.get_or_create(**data)
                else:
                    for form in formset:
                        new_data={
                                'cont':form.cleaned_data.get('cont'),
                                'cont_debit':form.cleaned_data.get('cont_debit'),
                                'cont_credit':form.cleaned_data.get('cont_credit'),
                                'balanta':form.cleaned_data.get('balanta'),
                        }
                        cont_complete,created=Conturi.objects.get_or_create(**new_data)
    else:
        balanta_form=BalantaForm()
        formset=ConturiInlineFormSet(instance=balanta)
    return render_to_response('sitfin/balanta_introducere.html',{'balanta_form':balanta_form,'formset':formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formset.cleaned_data` is a list of the individual forms `cleaned_data`. You need to iterate over `formset` and create a `Conturi` object for each:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset:
        cont, created=Conturi.objects.get_or_create(**form.cleaned_data)
```

**UPDATE:**

To protect yourself from errors resulting from additional form fields that do not correspond to model attributes, it's better to explicitly provide the arguments to `get_or_create` instead of using `**form.cleaned_data`.

```
if formset.is_valid():
   for form in formset:
       data = {
           'cont': form.cleaned_data.get('cont'),
           'cont_debit': form.cleaned_data.get('cont_debit'),
           'cont_credit': form.cleaned_data.get('cont_credit'),
           'balanta': form.cleaned_data.get('balanta'),
       }
       cont, created = Conturi.objects.get_or_create(**data)
```

It's basically the same procedure, but now you know exactly which arguments are being passed to `get_or_create`.

Comment: Thanks man but now i ran in another issue, it's something about the fields of the Conturi model....i think it's the foreignkey. I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: The error is being introduced by your use of `**` to map the dictionary to function arguments. Apparently, a `DELETE` key is in one or all of the `cleaned_data` dictionaries. Since that doesn't exist as an attribute on your model, you get the error. Either manually create the arguments to `get_or_create` or alter your form such that `DELETE` is no longer passed. While manually creating the arguments is more verbose, it's also much safer, so that would be my recommended approach.

Comment: I tried something but i get the error above. You gave me good advise but i'm not sure i'm going on the right truck to exactly what i try to achieve. What i want to do is this: "on the "Conturi part of the form" is to see if the cont is on the database, the form should update it with the value in the input box and if it is not in the db, the form should create it and the corresponding cont_debit or cont_credit."

Comment: `get_or_create` is really your only outlet for that. You could go the long way with a try..except block that attempts to get the right cont and when it doesn't exists (in except), you create it, but that's all `get_or_create` is really doing.

Comment: About manually creating the arguments for get_or_create can you please tell me if i am on the right track(question edited) or what should i read/learn first "Python for newbies" should be great:)

Comment: Updated answer above to give you some guidance.

Comment: You sure know what you're doing! I understand now. get_or_create arguments should be a dictionary. I have to learn more. thank you very much!

Comment: They don't *have* to be a dictionary. You can merely use a dictionary along with `**` to expand the dictionary into arguments. You could also just do `get_or_create(cont=form.cleaned_data.get('cont'), cont_debit...`. The point you need to take away from here is that whatever is passed to `get_or_create`, however it gets passed, must all be attributes on your model. My method above merely assures that they are; nothing special other than that.

Comment: Aha. I tried something like this: get_or_create(cont=form.cleaned_data.get('cont') but i did form.cleaned_data['cont']. I understand and again, i should learn a little more.Thanks again.

Comment: At the LAST UPDATE i have the current state. It's doing nothing when the data in the form stays the same and if i change something (like a cont_debit) it's making a new entry of only that "cont"(a step forward). I'm getting close but i want to update the existing "cont"...please help.

Comment: `get_or_create` is only going to work if you pass *something* that is a key for the row (unique).